# Convert a RGB 3-band Tiff to a singleband colored image in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have a RGB 3-band GeoTiff which gives me a nice looking when loaded in ArcGIS. Now i want to convert it to a simple colored image. My goal is to have an image which can be displayed the same in different software. (I know that i can change symbology of raster in every software, but i don't want to do that.) I have no analysis or processing need for this image, and only its view is important for me. How can i do that in ArcGIS?
What i have done: using Copy Raster tool, but unfortunately 'RGB to colormap' option is grayed out for this raster. I also tried Raster Calculator to add band values together, but output is not colored.

Comment: If you want to keep the same view in different software, it is better to leave it in RGB (3*8bit), otherwise you will depend on a colormap that will not be interpreted by any software.

Comment: I don't understand why this is impossible. For example, I can use Print Screen bottom and have a copy of current view in jpg format which always will be displayed the same. So why GIS software can't produce this output for me?

Comment: a jpg is an RGB file, and you can change it displays (darker/more contrast/ or even modify the band order to change the colors).

Comment: @Luke this solution does not work. It produces 3-band images. A new soultion: It is strange that File>Export Map nearly produces what i want. I set 8-bit in that dialog and it creates an image with Color Map which is viewed exactly the same in QGIS and in Windows. Though, it introduces small noices in output picture. Because of this kind of solutions, I think there should be a way in GIS tools to produce the same output without noise.

Comment: A small clarification: In fact, my original problem goes to GeoServer and creating a good SLD for raster files. I want to avoid creating that complicated SLD. If i can convert my 16-bit RGB image to a single-band image while preserving the view (like all other normal photos in windows which have fixed view ), i can be sure that GeoServer displays the image as it is displayed in windows or ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the bit depth (pixel type) to 8_BIT_UNSIGNED for this.

Comment: Helene was right. My data is 16-bit and by setting pixel type to 8-bit, now Copy Raster tool woks. But unfortunately it gives a 1-band image which is  really darker than original image. My problem still exist (i.e. producing a 1-band image with the same view). Colormap does not suit to original view.

Comment: I think the darker display is only due to the default stretch applied to the image upon loading. The actual image is the same as the original one, and resetting the default stretch to "None" should solve this. You might see different results in different software, because the parameters of default way of displaying the image varies.

Comment: @Hélène Your post could be considered as an answer, but please give more information as why it is so. We prefer longer answers. You could edit your post to add some of the content of your comment.

Comment: Finally, i could get it to work. First exporting data with checkbox 'Use Rederer' and then Copy Raster tool with checkbox 'RGB to colormap.' Meanwhile, this produces some NODATA values which should be handled in another way.

Answer (score 0):

"Color maps are capable of supporting any bit depth except floating point."

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/raster-functions/colormap-function.htm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).